# Selecting math font with unicode-math in beamer with XeLaTeX

Tags: beamer, xetex, unicode-math

I'm trying to use `unicode-math` in XeLaTeX to use Asana Math in a beamer presentation, but I am unable to use select the font for letters in math mode. See the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
%\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{Asana Math} % has no effect

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Maths font test:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item math letters display in Libertine: $abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz$
    \item math operators and blackboard letters display in Asana Math: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \sum \mathbb{E}$
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

The letters are displayed in Linux Libertine, instead of Asana Math.
I tried to tinker with the `range` option in `unicode-math` (as documented in the [manual](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unicode-math.pdf)), to no avail.

Strangely, when I compile the document as an article, I get the results I expect. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}%  don't change fonts inside beamer

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
...
```